# How to mock IAuthorizationService in .net core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, nsubstitute

I'm using this resource authorization in my controller:

```
var result = await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, document, operation);
```

I need to test my controller, and I need the authorization to pass in the test.

I tried:

```
_substituteAuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(Arg.Any<ClaimsPrincipal>(), null, Arg.Any<IEnumerable<IAuthorizationRequirement>>())
            .ReturnsForAnyArgs(new AuthorizationResult(......));
```

but I can't *new* an AuthorizationResult because it doesn't have a public constructor.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: return from the static method `AuthorzationResult.Success()`

Comment: [AuthorizationResult.cs Source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization/AuthorizationResult.cs) I second Jasen's suggestion

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not much detail here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizationresult?view=aspnetcore-2.0

But you can return from the static method(s)

```
AuthorizationResult.Success()
AuthorizationResult.Failed()
```